# Time complexity for computing sum of first $n$ squares

Tags: computational-complexity

I'm trying to compute **time complexity for computing sum of first $\mathbf{n}$ squares.** Actually, this is a problem from the textbook (A course in number theory and cryptography).

The question is to compute time complexity for LHS and RHS of the formula:
$\sum_{j=1}^n j^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$

The answers from the textbook says $O(n{log}^2{n})$, but I found tighter bound for the algorithm as $O(log^2{n})$.

The reason is: We think of an algorithm as summing 
$1 \times 1$, 
$2 \times 2$, 
..., 
$n\times n$
(Total of $n$ steps)

On $j$-th step, the length is $O(log^2{j})$.
Summing $n$ terms,
$O(log^2{1})+O(log^2{2})+...+O(log^2{n})\leq C*O(log^2{n})$, where $C$ is a constant.

Therefore, I got $Time(LHS)=O(log^2{n})$.

**Is this correct?
if I got wrong, could you tell me why?**

thanks a lot :)

Comment: There is no constant $C$ that can satisfy your inequality.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your $C$ isn't a constant, it depends on $n$. The larger $n$ is, the more terms you have, and the sequence $\ln^2 n$ doesn't grow fast enough for the final few terms to dominate. This means that your $C$ must grow with $n$.

Comment: Ooops that was a silly question. So each $ln^2{j}$'s are bounded by $ln^2{n}$ and there are n such terms, so the time complexity becomes $O(n*ln^2{n})$.

Comment: @JHLEE Yes. At least that proves that it cannot be $O(\ln^2 n)$. Proving that $O(n\ln^2 n)$ is in some sense the best one can do (that it's not, say $O(\sqrt n\ln^2 n)$) is a slightly different matter.

Comment: Got it. Thx a lot!